# How do I get a scrapy item (or a dict / named tuple) into a postgres stored procudure (function) performing an insert using psycopg2

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, scrapy, psycopg2

I am creating a service layer for a database, and hence I am creating functions to perform certain operations. Atm some of them are simple asynchronous inserts. However, they have a huge amount of parameters.

I am using scrapy to spider data and I use the [`item` concept](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.14/topics/items.html) from scrapy, which has a python dict-like api. I don't want to have to parameterise all of the fields in the stored procedure signature / stored procedure call construction, or the insert statement.

Notice that the composite type is declared twice to begin with. 1st in the `create table` statement in postgres, and secondly in scrapy using the item interface. So :

What is the cleanest way of getting a python dict-like entity into postgres using pyscopg2, without having to parameterise whilst at the same time being future proof (i.e., no positional  paramterization).

I'm thinking `tablename%ROWTYPE` should be declared as the stored procedure input parameter, but how do I map the python dict-like object when I create the execute query string ? Something to do with [composite type casing in psycopg2](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#composite-types-casting) I think. But I can't see the complete picture from the documentation.

For the sake of argument lets consider a user table `CREATE TABLE( name character varying, id integer primary key)` with a corresponding scrapy type, and the primary id is unique implicitly in the domain.  Any comments on how the insert would look like incase default values and a pkey serializer was in place would also help :D

Could I use the [Sql Adaption Protocol](http://packages.python.org/psycopg2/extensions.html#sql-adaptation-protocol-objects) to subclass the scrapy item with generic routines to turn a scrapy item into a postgres composite type ? Would this be wise ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Postgres wiki has this to say:

> A last item I would like to show you is how to insert multiple rows
>   using a dictionary. If you had the following:
>
> ```
> namedict = ({"first_name":"Joshua", "last_name":"Drake"},
>             {"first_name":"Steven", "last_name":"Foo"},
>             {"first_name":"David", "last_name":"Bar"})
> ```
>
> You could easily insert all three rows within the dictionary by using:
>
> ```
> cur = conn.cursor()
> cur.executemany("""INSERT INTO bar(first_name,last_name) VALUES (%(first_name)s, %(last_name)s)""", namedict)
> ```

The hstore module has a function to create structured row types :

```
CREATE TABLE test (col1 integer, col2 text, col3 text);

SELECT * FROM populate_record(null::test,
                              '"col1"=>"456", "col2"=>"zzz"');
 col1 | col2 | col3 
------+------+------
  456 | zzz  | 
(1 row)
```